# Apache CFX Custom LoggingInInterceptor is not overriding

Tags: java, apache, logging, spring-boot

I am trying to create custom LoggingInInterceptor , but code is not coming to custom part at all.My sample SOP @@@@@@@@handleMessage is even not printed.I am using Apache CFX with SpringBoot application to consume SOAP services.So tried to customize the request and response for logger.Please help to find the issue.

**Custom Interceptor:**

```
@Component
public class CustomLoggingInterceptor extends LoggingInInterceptor{     

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@handleMessage"+this.getClass().getName());
        Logger logger = getCustomMessageLogger(message);
        if (logger != null && (writer != null || logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO))) {
            logging(logger, message);
        }
    }

        Logger getCustomMessageLogger(Message message) {
        if (isLoggingDisabledNow(message)) {
            return null; 
        }
        Endpoint ep = message.getExchange().getEndpoint();
        if (ep == null || ep.getEndpointInfo() == null) {
            return getLogger();
        }
        EndpointInfo endpoint = ep.getEndpointInfo();
        if (endpoint.getService() == null) {
            return getLogger();
        }
        Logger logger = endpoint.getProperty("MessageLogger", Logger.class);
        if (logger == null) {
            String logName = "org.apache.cxf.services." ;
            logger = LogUtils.getL7dLogger(this.getClass(), null, logName);
            endpoint.setProperty("MessageLogger", logger);
        }
        return logger;
    }
}
```

**Service call:-**

```
    UserService service = getUserServiceForEndpoint("URL");
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(service);
    Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint();

    endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOutInterceptor);
    endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(loggingOutInterceptor);
    endpoint.getOutFaultInterceptors().add(loggingOutInterceptor);

    endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(customLoggingInterceptor );
    endpoint.getInFaultInterceptors().add(customLoggingInterceptor);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By customizing the LoggingOutInterceptor my problem is resolved as below,

```
@Component
public class CredentialMaskingLoggingOutInterceptor extends LoggingOutInterceptor{

    @Autowired
    ApplicationProperties appProps;

    /**
     * To mask user credentials from the logging so that which will not be misused.
     */
    @Override
    protected String formatLoggingMessage(LoggingMessage buffer) {
        return buffer.toString().replace(appProps.getUsername(), "SOAP_USERNAME").replace(appProps.getPassword(), "SOAP_PASSWORD");
    }
}
```

**Updated Log snippet:**

```
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken"><wsse:Username>SOAP_USERNAME</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">SOAP_PASSWORD</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken>
```